# Self join when the number of sub-select is not known

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table in which spouse and children are linked to main user.

```
+----------------+-------------------+----------+------------------------------+------------------+
|  Id | User_ID           | Rel_Type | Applno                       | RelationWith     |
+----------------+-------------------+----------+------------------------------+------------------+
|        1234756 | aambu ghosha      | self     | 201708180921      | aambu ghosha     |
|        1235146 | parvati ghosha    | spouse   |  NULL | aambu ghosha     |
|        1235147 | ananta ghosha    | Children   | 201708180921      | aambu ghosha     |
|         500787 | anant01011975     | self     | 20170811171403999L    | anant01011975    |
|         501626 | chandu1988        | children | NULL                         | anant01011975    |
|        1706064 | atmaram sutar     | self     | 20170821094537517L  | atmaram sutar    |
|        1706494 | venu sutar        | spouse   | 20170821094537517L  | atmaram sutar    |
```

In the above example, the main applicant "aambu ghosha" is "self" (main applicant). The spouse and Children (parvati and ananta) needs to be considered as a single applicant.

```
aambu ghosha 3
anant01011975 2
atmaram sutar 2
```

The count of main applicants should include their family members. The expected result is shown above.
I guess this can achieved using self join, but I am not sure how many children  are linked to main applicant. What is best approach to find the count?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30945c/2/0

---

update:

How do I self - join and update the application number that is linked to main applicant? For e.g. second record NULL value should be changed to 201708180921.

Comment: how many levels are allowed? just one?

Comment: Yes. Only 1 level is allowed, but a head can have multiple dependants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have just one level of children, this will work

```
SELECT userid, count(*)
FROM tab p
JOIN tab ch ON p.user_id = ch.RelationWith
WHERE p.user_id = p.RelationWith
GROUP BY userid
```

Actually, even simpler query produce the result requested by you

```
SELECT RelationWith, count(*)
FROM tab
GROUP BY RelationWith
```